# Get users name from table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display user name from users table. I get article information for example `{{$article->title}}`
but i doesnt get users info.

Model Article

```
 protected $fillable = ['title','slug','description_short','description','image_path','meta_title', 
 'meta_description','meta_keyword','published', 'created_by', 'modified_by','author_id'];

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
```

Model User

```
protected $fillable = [
   'id', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
];

public function articles(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@forelse ($articles as $article)
        <tr>   
            @foreach($article as $userss)
                <?php var_dump($userss)  ?>
              <div class="display-commentttt">
                @if (isset($userss->users->name))
                 <?php var_dump($userss->users->name); ?>
                    <div class="user-login">{{ $userss->user->name }}
                    </div>
                @elseif  (isset($userss->users->id))
                 <?php var_dump($userss->users->name); ?>
                    <div class="user-login">{{ $userss->users->id }}
                    </div>
                @endif

            @endforeach

          <td>{{$article->title}}</td>
          <td>{{$article->published}}</td>
@endforelse
```

In my article Controler

```
public function index(){
         return view('admin.articles.index',[
        'articles' => Article::with(['user'])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily possible by **Eloquent**. In your Article model rename your function users() to user();

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
```

}

then go to your controller's method and get article data using following method

```
    public function view_articles(){

      //you must have to import Article model at the top
       $articles  = Article::with(['user'])->get();
       dd($articles); //this will show response. 
     return view('view_file')->with(compact('articles'));



    }

//inside your view file
@foreach ($articles as $article)
        <tr>   
            @foreach($article as $userss)

               <td>{{$article->title}}</td>
          <td>{{$article->published}}</td>
             <td>{{$article->user->name}}</td>  

            @endforeach


@endforeach
```

Comment: I updated the question, please look. It doesnt work

Comment: you can see my index function ?

Comment: ya I am getting and seeing it.

Comment: It looks like you're using `author_id` to relate the user, so it should be `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');`

Comment: @kerbholz I just thought of it myself. Thank you very much for responding to the question and helped